# Maintaining Context in XSLT Functions

Tags: xml, xslt

For the following XML:

```
<X12>
    <GROUP>
        <TS_850>
            <REF>
                <REF01>CR</REF01>
                <REF02>53222</REF02>
            </REF>
        </TS_850>
    </GROUP>
</X12>
```

This code works:

```
<xsl:variable name="REF02">
    <xsl:for-each select="X12/GROUP/TS_850/REF">
        <xsl:if test="REF01='CR'">
            <xsl:value-of select="REF02"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

...

<xsl:value-of select="$REF02"/>
```

However, this code does not:

```
<xsl:function name="test:valueWhereValue">
    <xsl:param name="context" />
    <xsl:param name="conditionalElement" />
    <xsl:param name="conditionalValue" />
    <xsl:param name="outputElement"/>

    <xsl:for-each select="$context">
        <xsl:if test="$conditionalElement = $conditionalValue">
            <xsl:value-of select="$outputElement" />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:function>

...

<xsl:copy-of select="test:valueWhereValue(X12/GROUP/TS_850/REF, REF01, 'CR', REF02)"></xsl:copy-of>
```

As best I can tell, the two code snippets should be functionally equivalent.  However, according to my debugger, REF01 and REF02 don't actually reference nodes the way I would expect in the function version.  It seems like I'm not actually entering the proper context with my for-each statement in the function, which prevents the children nodes from selecting properly.  Why is that, and how can I fix my function?

Comment: They're not equivalent because in `test:valueWhereValue(X12/GROUP/TS_850/REF, REF01, 'CR', REF02)` the second and fourth parameters are looking for a `REF01` and `REF02` element at the same level as the `X12`, not inside the `REF`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI, this:

```
<xsl:variable name="REF02">
    <xsl:for-each select="X12/GROUP/TS_850/REF">
        <xsl:if test="REF01='CR'">
            <xsl:value-of select="REF02"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

is this, under the conditin that there is exactly one `REF01` equal to `'CR'` per `TS_850`:

```
<xsl:variable name="REF02" select="X12/GROUP/TS_850/REF[REF01 = 'CR']/REF02" />
```

Starting with XSLT 2.0, you might want to prefer `<xsl:sequence>` instead of `<xsl:value-of>` for the return value. Sequences are a lot more versatile than the plain string the function would otherwise return.

So your function could look more like this:

```
<xsl:function name="test:valueWhereValue">
    <xsl:param name="conditionalElement" />
    <xsl:param name="conditionalValue" />
    <xsl:param name="outputElement"/>

    <xsl:if test="$conditionalElement = $conditionalValue">
        <xsl:sequence select="$outputElement" />
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:function>
```

and the call like this:

```
<xsl:template match="X12/GROUP/TS_850/REF">
    <xsl:copy-of select="test:valueWhereValue(REF01, 'CR', REF02)" />
</xsl:template>
```

---

When you take a step back, your function is a rater complex replacement for this:

```
<xsl:template match="X12/GROUP/TS_850/REF">
    <xsl:if test="REF01 = 'CR'">
        <xsl:copy-of select="REF02" />
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

which in turn is a rather complex way to say this:

```
<xsl:template match="X12/GROUP/TS_850/REF[REF01 = 'CR']">
    <xsl:copy-of select="REF02" />
</xsl:template>
```

which *in turn* is a rather complex way to say *this*:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="X12/GROUP/TS_850/REF[REF01 = 'CR']/REF02" />
```

so it's rather a pointless function to have in the first place.

Comment: I don't think that it is true that "The current node will not change for a function call". If you are inside a function, called from a template, and you attempt to use something like `<xsl:value-of select="path(.)"/>`, you will get the error:  `Error XPDY0002 while evaluating ... There is no context item`

Comment: @mcwayliffe You're absolutely right. The context item stays the same for `<xsl:call-template>`, it's not available in a function. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @mcwayliffe I was held up a little, but I've updated the answer now.